# TelephonyManager listen onSignalStrengthsChanged runs only 1 Time

Tags: android, telephonymanager, signal-strength

I write a simple code to listen onSignalStrengthsChanged :

```
package ir.yadgari.myservingcell;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TelephonyManager Tel;
    Integer mCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Tel.listen(new mListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
    }

    class  mListener extends PhoneStateListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength sStrength)
        {
            TextView tvStrength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStrength);
            TextView tvCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
            tvStrength.setText(sStrength.toString());
            mCount++;
            tvCount.setText("Activity runs for " + String.valueOf(mCount) + " times");
            //showMyMessage(String.valueOf(sStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()));
        }
    }
}
```

method "onSignalStrengthsChanged" run only at the first, and don't run at network signal changes.

Note: I searched the internet and found many content about this, but don't solve my issue.

Comment: Did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For me, work well with below code.

```
package com.example.h0136899.phonestrengthchange;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textview = null;
TextView textview1 = null;
TelephonyManager Tel;
int mCount = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    Tel.listen(new mListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
}

class  mListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength sStrength)
    {
        textview.setText(sStrength.toString());
        mCount++;
        textview1.setText("Activity runs for " + String.valueOf(mCount) + " times");
        //showMyMessage(String.valueOf(sStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()));
    }
 }
}
```